# How to call a generic method in the driver class

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to call this method in the driver class with Integers but it doesn't work. Please can anyone help me

```
public SLL<T> missing(SLL<T> testList)
{
    if(this.head == null)
    {
        return testList;
    }
    if(testList.head == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    SLL<T> returnList = new SLL<T>();
    Element<T> ptr = testList.head;

    while(ptr!= null)
    {
        if(!isMember(ptr.data))
        {
            returnList.append(ptr.data);
            return returnList;
        }
        ptr = ptr.next;
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling it? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: method call in the driver class. I'm not sure how to call it, i have created an object in the driver class, and i need to give it to check for an integer

Comment: @Armee hint: we can't see your code if you don't post it. Post what you tried. Post the exact and complete error message you get.

Comment: myStack.missing(new Integer(3));

Comment: error is incompatible types, cannot be converted to SLL<Integer>

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `return returnList;` in the while-loop. If the if-condition is met, the while-loop exits at that point.

Comment: how do i call it though in the driver with an integer paramter?

Comment: This method is probably in the "SLL" class. You can create a new instance by using `SLL<Integer> sll = new SLL<>();` and call `sll.missing(<other SLL>);`

Comment: Would really appreciate if you could mark this as the solving answer (don't really know  how its named)

Comment: i'm not quite sure how to mark it as solved,please could you direct me